# Complexity of counting the number of Good-perfect matching in the bipartite graph

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, co.combinatorics, counting-complexity, permanent

Let's $G=(U, V, E)$ be a balanced bipartite graph which $|U|=|V|=n$ and $|E|=n*(n-1)$; All nodes in $U$ are connected to all nodes in $V$ except $u_i$ to $v_i$ for $1\leq i \leq n$.

Definition1: Cross edges are two edges in $E$, one with two end points $u_i$, $v_j$ and the other with $u_j$, $v_i$.
Definition2: Good-perfect matching is a perfect matching with no cross edges.

What is the complexity of counting the number of Good-perfect matching in $G$?

Comment: This question suffers the *exact same* problem as your previous qeustion: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/coumputing-the-permanent-of-a-0-1-matrix-which-only-the-entries-on-the-main-diago

Comment: Cross posted to math.se: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16419/complexity-of-counting-the-number-of-good-perfect-matching-in-bipartite-graph

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only one instance for each size n. Thus, the problem is clearly in P/poly, and cannot possibly be #P-complete unless the polynomial hierarchy collapses.

In fact, it is polynomial-time computable. You can compute the first few terms of the sequence, and find that it goes 2, 6, 24, 160 ... . You can then look at the online encyclopedia of integer sequences and [find it](http://oeis.org/A038205). When you look at the page for this sequence, you find a polynomial-time formula for computing it.